# pulseaudio no sound card mplayer ok

Tags: 12.10, sound, usb, pulseaudio, alsa

I'm running version 12.10. My PC has an built-in sound card and 3 usb sound cards of the same type. mplayer works ok for all of them using the argument `-ao alsa:device=hw=2.0` for instance. `vlc --aout=hw=2.0` does not work. pacmd does not list any card. Starting pulseaudio manually results in `Failed to open module "alsa": file not found`. hwinfo shows the built-in card only. lsusb shows the connected cards correctly and the corresponding files `/sys/class/sound/pcmC?D0p/uevent` look ok as well. Please advice.

Comment: Regarding VLC, could you be a little more specific than "does not work"?

Comment: Sorry, '...not work' means no sound. In the meantime I removed pulseaudio. vlc now connects to alsa and sees all alsa cards available, but it ignores the command line switch 'hw=' and opens the default alsa device, which most likely is the built-in card having no speaker attached. Anyway, it looks like little progress is made, but the target is still unreached...

Comment: Wow, a typo prevented vlc from using the wanted device: the needed option is --aout hw=2.0 (a blank between aout and hw, no =)...

Answer (score 0):

In mplayer's `ao` option, any `:` or `,` characters in the device name must be replaced with `=` or `.` to avoid some silly conflicts in the mplayer option parsing code.
The actual device name you're using is `hw:2,0`.

VLC's `aout` option specifies the audio output *module name*; the device name would be specified with the `alsadev` option:

```
vlc --aout=alsa --alsadev=hw:2,0
```

Comment: Thank you CL, I tried it. vlc would not accept the option alsadev. It looks like it was renamed to alsa-audio-device. Since 'aply -l' reported card 1: PCM2702 [Burr-Brown Japan PCM2702], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

Comment: sorry for breaking the input here

Comment: aplay list the wanted card as #1, so I tried mplayer with this card using -ao alsa:device=hw=1.0 and it worked. Then I tried vlc using --aout=alsa --alsa-audio-device=hw:1,0 and I got several error messages: cannot open ALSA device "hw:1,0": No such file or directory and The audio device "hw:1,0" could not be used:
No such file or directory. Please advice...

Comment: This may be usefule as well: ALSA lib pcm_hw.c:1401:(_snd_pcm_hw_open) Invalid value for card

Comment: I guess `aplay -D hw:1 something.wav` doesn't work either? Are the permissions on the files in `/dev/snd/` correct?